# Is there a defined set of JSON parser tests that validate the majority of edge cases?

Tags: json

I'm researching some JSON parsers, but some are home-grown.  Is there a validation test that can be run against a json parser which verifies that the parser is "valid" and serializes/deserializes JSON string properly?

Comment: You need a JSON parser for what language and/or environment?

Comment: Here is a test suite: http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/ - all failures except 1 and 18 are imho reasonable

Answer (score 7):

It seems that someone attempted to write a test suite [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-test-suite/downloads/list)

It is used in another parser [project](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/PerformanceTesting) to validate its implementation:

It's in java, don't know if its fit.

(someone has written some tests for python too [her](http://codespeak.net/svn/z3/jsonserver/trunk/jsontest.py)e)