# Look for JSON example with all allowed combinations of structure in max depth 2 or 3

Tags: json, combinations, grammar

I've wrote a program which process JSON objects. Now I want to verify if I've missed something.

Is there an **JSON-example** of all allowed JSON structure combinations? Something like this:

```
{
    "key1" : "value",
    "key2" : 1,
    "key3" : {"key1" : "value"},
    "key4" : [
                [
                    "string1",
                    "string2"
                ],
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                ...
    ],
    "key5" : true,
    "key6" : false,
    "key7" : null,
    ...
}
```

As you can see at http://json.org/ on the right hand side the grammar of JSON isn't quite difficult, but I've got several exceptions because I've forgotten to handles some structure combinations which are possible. E.g. inside an array there can be "string, number, object, array, true, false, null" but my program couldn't handle arrays inside an array until I ran into an exception. So everything was fine until I got this valid JSON object with arrays inside an array.

I want to test my program with a JSON object (which I'm looking for). After this test I want to be feel certain that my program handle every possible valid JSON structure on earth without an exception.

I don't need nesting in depth 5 or so. I only need something in nested depth 2 or max 3. With all base types which nested all allowed base types, inside this base type.

Comment: There are an infinite number of combinations, so there no no such eample. Anyway, if you have correctly implemented all basic types, then how could you fail to implement arrays correctly, since arrays are just a list of basic types inside `[]`"? By the way, there is no known concept of anything called a "JSON object". There are JSON strings and then there are JavaScript values.

Comment: If you want to test your library thoroughly, including error handling, obviously you also need examples of **invalid** JSON.

Comment: Look at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark/master/data/citm_catalog.json and other sample data sets in that repo.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805979/is-there-a-defined-set-of-json-parser-tests-that-validate-the-majority-of-edge-c.

Comment: Some must-pass and must-fail examples: http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/test.zip

Comment: @torazaburo: I use Java with org.json object are called JsonObjects (including the root object) there.

Comment: Then tag your question with the `java` and `json-object` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of escaped characters and objects within an object?

```
{
    "key1" : {
                 "key1" : "value",
                 "key2" : [
                              "String1",
                              "String2"
                 ],
             },
    "key2" : "\"This is a quote\"",
    "key3" : "This contains an escaped slash: \\",
    "key4" : "This contains accent charachters: \u00eb \u00ef",
}
```

Note: `\u00eb` and `\u00ef` are resp. charachters ë and ï

Answer (score 0):

Choose a programming language that support **json**.
Try to load your **json**, on fail the exception's message is descriptive.

Example:

**Python:**

```
import json, sys;
json.loads(open(sys.argv[1]).read())
```

Generate:

```
import random, json, os, string

def json_null(depth = 0):
    return None

def json_int(depth = 0):
    return random.randint(-999, 999)

def json_float(depth = 0):
    return random.uniform(-999, 999)

def json_string(depth = 0):
    return ''.join(random.sample(string.printable, random.randrange(10, 40)))

def json_bool(depth = 0):
    return random.randint(0, 1) == 1

def json_list(depth):
    lst = []
    if depth:
        for i in range(random.randrange(8)):
            lst.append(gen_json(random.randrange(depth)))
    return lst

def json_object(depth):
    obj = {}
    if depth:
        for i in range(random.randrange(8)):
            obj[json_string()] = gen_json(random.randrange(depth))
    return obj

def gen_json(depth = 8):
    if depth:
        return random.choice([json_list, json_object])(depth)
    else:
        return random.choice([json_null, json_int, json_float, json_string, json_bool])(depth)

print(json.dumps(gen_json(), indent = 2))
```

Comment: The Problem isn't **my json**. It's my **program**. My program handles all JSONs I've tested until now. I've extended it every time I've got an exception. I need now some JSON-example, which has all combinations so I can test if everything works fine with my program. This JSON should has some cascading with all allowed types as you can see in my upper post.

Comment: do you need valid and invalid json examples?

Comment: I need a valid example of all possible cascading members which are allowed for every type

Comment: @mahan *I need a valid example of all possible cascading members which are allowed for every type*: That's unlikely, since there are obviously an infinite number. By the way, by "cascading" do you mean "nested"?

Comment: @Dombi Szabolcs: Thanks, this is a interesting generator. But this isn't what I'm looking for.